# Error: <Composite Controller> could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I *bake* my table user_routes and CakePHP create class Controllers with name *UserRoutesController.php*, but, i call the link 'http://[server]/userroutes' and the follow error that show to me:

```
Error: UserroutesController could not be found.

Error: Create the class UserroutesController below in file: app/Controller/UserroutesController.php

<?php
class UserroutesController extends AppController {

}

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
```

I checked all convention names and .htaccess and that's all ok.

best regards,
Marcos

Comment: There's a difference between `UserRoutes` and `Userroutes` (the capitalization of the `R`)

Comment: Hello Maerlyn, I tried to rename the class name to * Userroutes * (and the file too) but other errors were presented. I developed the site in Win7 platform but I'm putting into production on Linux (Ubuntu Server) and this error was not presented to me.

Note: I followed the convention in accordance with the documentation submitted in CakePHP for compound names of tables.

Comment: Windows filesystems are case-insensitive, linux filesystems are case-sensitive. Make sure you have the same capitalization in your code and in the file (and directory) names.

Comment: Hello, so the class name 'UserRoutesController' as the file name 'UserRoutesController.php' are equal. My other classes 'PostController', 'UserController', etc. work properly, however, that it has a compound name shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

My fault!

I was accessing the URL as

> http://[server]/userroutes

but the correct thing

> http://[server]/user_routes

Marcos